# (theoretical) Negative Binomial Distribution using Matlab

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, matlab

I was trying to solve some exercises on Matlab in order to improve my skills and I stumbled upon this question:

> For the (theoretical) Negative Binomial distribution with parameters r = 5, p = 0.4, use Matlab to find the mean, μ, and variance, $\sigma^2$.

I have found the answers to be μ = 7.500 and $\sigma^2$ = 18.7500. Now, the second part of the question is a bit tough for me:

> For each sample size n = 1, 5, 10:
>
> ```
>  1) Generate 1,000 random samples from this distribution (as a 1000 x n or an n x 1000 matrix)
>  2) Find the 1,000 sample means (Hint: store them for further calculation)
>  3) Compute the mean and variance of the 1,000 sample means.
> ```

I have tried to use the function `RND = nbinrnd(R,P,m,n)`, where R = 5, P = 0.4, m = 1000, and n = 1. If that's correct, I assume that would be for the sample size 1? How can I adjust this in order to calculate for size 5 and 10? I have tried to find an answer on the web, but I've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

From the MATLAB documentation:

> RND = nbinrnd(R,P) is a matrix of random numbers chosen from a
>   negative binomial distribution with corresponding number of successes,
>   R and probability of success in a single trial, P. R and P can be
>   vectors, matrices, or multidimensional arrays that have the same size,
>   which is also the size of RND. A scalar input for R or P is expanded
>   to a constant array with the same dimensions as the other input.
>
> RND = nbinrnd(R,P,m,n,...) or RND = nbinrnd(R,P,[m,n,...]) generates
>   an m-by-n-by-... array. The R, P parameters can each be scalars or
>   arrays of the same size as R.
>
> The simplest motivation for the negative binomial is the case of
>   successive random trials, each having a constant probability P of
>   success. The number of extra trials you must perform in order to
>   observe a given number R of successes has a negative binomial
>   distribution. However, consistent with a more general interpretation
>   of the negative binomial, nbinrnd allows R to be any positive value,
>   including nonintegers.

Short version: try it and find out.

Long version, $m$ and $n$ give you an $m$ by $n$ matrix. So if $m = 5$ and $n = 1$, then you get a 5 by 1 matrix of negative binomial random variables.

If $m = 5$ and $n = 10$, you get a 5 by 10 matrix.

If you just need to generate $N$ samples, set $m = 1$ and $n = N$, or vice versa.

Comment: I tried it using: RND = nbinrnd(5,0.4,1000,1) (for sample n=1)
then took mean(RND,1) and std(RND,1) and I've got 7.6460 and 4.3593 respectively.
For sample n=5 I used RND = nbinrnd(5, 0.4, 1000, 5) and with the same commands mean(RND,1) and std(RND,1) I've got 5 different means and variances, so I found the mean value of those results to be 7.4722 and 4.2424.
Same thing for sample n=10: I've got 7.4574 and 4.3351
Now, suppose they are correct, consider the means and variances for the different sample sizes: how do they seem to relate to the true mean and variance (μ=7.5000 and σ^2=18.7500)?

Comment: Well, 7.47 is awfully close to 7.5, and 4.33 is pretty close to the square root of 18.75. Remember that std gives $\sigma$, not $\sigma^2$.